# For any integers $a, b, d$, if $d | a$ and $d | b$, then $d$ | $(3a + 5b)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I guessed the hypothesis and the conclusion and I just have to prove it.

Hypothesis: $d$ | $a$ and $d$ | $b$
Conclusion: $d$ | $(3a + 5b)$

If $d$ | $a$, then $a = dk$ for some integer $k$.
If $d$ | $b$, then $b = dl$ for some integer $l$.
then $3a+5b$ = $d ⋅ (3k+5l)$

Is there more to this proof or is this all I need to write. Need help please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: $\;3a+5b=3dk+5dl\,$. Now find an $m$ such that $\;3a+5b=dm\,$.

Comment: can I say that $dm = 3dk + 5dl$?

Comment: Careful there with what you know vs. what you need to prove. First, you determined that $3a+5b=d \cdot (3k+5l)\,$. Then, you can say that $d \mid 3a+5b$ because $3a+5b=dm$ where $m=3k+5l\,$ based on what you first determined.

Comment: *what* next part?  You are done.

Comment: Is that the end of the proof?

Comment: Yes.  If $d*m = Q$ for some integer $m$ then $d$ divides $Q$.  $d*(3k+5l) = 3a+5b$.  So if $m = 3k+5l$ is an integer, $d$ divides $3a+5b$.  Is $3k + 5l$ an integer?

Comment: I believe yes, $3k + 5l$ is an integer.

Comment: I was being half facetious.  Of course $3k + 5l$ is an integer.  So $d*m = 3a+ 5b$ for some integer $m = 3k+5l$.  So, by definition, $d$ divides $3a + 5b$.  You are completely, totally, thoroughly, and absolutely, irrevokably done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You:

"If d | a, then a=dk for some integer k.

If d | b, then b=dl for some integer l.

then 3a+5b = d⋅(3k+5l)"

Me:

$3k+5l$ is some integer.

Since $3a+5b = d*(3k+5l)$ for some integer, $3k + 5l$, $d|3a + 5b$.

......

More general, more useful, and more powerful:  if $d|a$ and $d|b$ then $d$ divides any $\pm ak$ and any $\pm bm$ and any $\pm ak \pm bm$ for *ALL* possible combinations where $k,m$ are integers (positive, negative, or zero).  Can you prove that.